# Usage of super in conjunction with a django ModelForm class to alter the __init__ method

Tags: python, django, class, super

While trying out some code ideas I stumbled over a problem I cant seem to wrap my head around.

Please ignore the fact WHY I try to do this, the question is all about why its not working;)

So I want to create a formclass in which I overwrite the `__init__` method of the Baseclass but simply want to copy it.

Basically what I want to do is the following:

```
class A():
    def __init(self, a, b, c)__:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(B, self).__init__( a, b, c)
        
        # Do some stuff that was not implemented#
```

I would expect the `__init__`  method of B to work exactly like there would be no change, exept for the added stuff at the end. However in my Example something definately changed since my form isnt working any more afterwards:

```
class SignUpForm_test(forms.ModelForm):

    password_confirmed  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    # --> This is the important stuff, the rest is just for completeness <--#
    #########################################################################
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                    initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                    empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                    renderer=None):
        super().__init__( data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                    initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                    empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                    renderer=None)
    #########################################################################

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (  
                    "username",    
                    "email", 
                    "password"             
                )           
    
    def clean_password_confirmed(self):
        password             = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password_confirmed   = self.cleaned_data.get('password_confirmed')


        if password and password_confirmed:
            if password != password_confirmed:
                raise ValidationError(
                    message ='Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen',
                    code    ='password_mismatch',
                )
        # password_validation.validate_password(password_confirmed)        
        return password_confirmed
```

Thanks for any help to understand this!

Here is the source code for the ModelForm and the related BaseModelForm, so you dont have to look for it:

```
class BaseModelForm(BaseForm):
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
             initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
             empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
             renderer=None):
    opts = self._meta
    if opts.model is None:
        raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')
    if instance is None:
        # if we didn't get an instance, instantiate a new one
        self.instance = opts.model()
        object_data = {}
    else:
        self.instance = instance
        object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
    # if initial was provided, it should override the values from instance
    if initial is not None:
        object_data.update(initial)
    # self._validate_unique will be set to True by BaseModelForm.clean().
    # It is False by default so overriding self.clean() and failing to call
    # super will stop validate_unique from being called.
    self._validate_unique = False
    super().__init__(
        data, files, auto_id, prefix, object_data, error_class,
        label_suffix, empty_permitted, use_required_attribute=use_required_attribute,
        renderer=renderer,
    )
    for formfield in self.fields.values():
        apply_limit_choices_to_to_formfield(formfield)

def _get_validation_exclusions(self):
    """
    For backwards-compatibility, exclude several types of fields from model
    validation. See tickets #12507, #12521, #12553.
    """
    exclude = []
    # Build up a list of fields that should be excluded from model field
    # validation and unique checks.
    for f in self.instance._meta.fields:
        field = f.name
        # Exclude fields that aren't on the form. The developer may be
        # adding these values to the model after form validation.
        if field not in self.fields:
            exclude.append(f.name)

        # Don't perform model validation on fields that were defined
        # manually on the form and excluded via the ModelForm's Meta
        # class. See #12901.
        elif self._meta.fields and field not in self._meta.fields:
            exclude.append(f.name)
        elif self._meta.exclude and field in self._meta.exclude:
            exclude.append(f.name)

        # Exclude fields that failed form validation. There's no need for
        # the model fields to validate them as well.
        elif field in self._errors:
            exclude.append(f.name)

        # Exclude empty fields that are not required by the form, if the
        # underlying model field is required. This keeps the model field
        # from raising a required error. Note: don't exclude the field from
        # validation if the model field allows blanks. If it does, the blank
        # value may be included in a unique check, so cannot be excluded
        # from validation.
        else:
            form_field = self.fields[field]
            field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)
            if not f.blank and not form_field.required and field_value in form_field.empty_values:
                exclude.append(f.name)
    return exclude

def clean(self):
    self._validate_unique = True
    return self.cleaned_data

def _update_errors(self, errors):
    # Override any validation error messages defined at the model level
    # with those defined at the form level.
    opts = self._meta

    # Allow the model generated by construct_instance() to raise
    # ValidationError and have them handled in the same way as others.
    if hasattr(errors, 'error_dict'):
        error_dict = errors.error_dict
    else:
        error_dict = {NON_FIELD_ERRORS: errors}

    for field, messages in error_dict.items():
        if (field == NON_FIELD_ERRORS and opts.error_messages and
                NON_FIELD_ERRORS in opts.error_messages):
            error_messages = opts.error_messages[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
        elif field in self.fields:
            error_messages = self.fields[field].error_messages
        else:
            continue

        for message in messages:
            if (isinstance(message, ValidationError) and
                    message.code in error_messages):
                message.message = error_messages[message.code]

    self.add_error(None, errors)

def _post_clean(self):
    opts = self._meta

    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()

    # Foreign Keys being used to represent inline relationships
    # are excluded from basic field value validation. This is for two
    # reasons: firstly, the value may not be supplied (#12507; the
    # case of providing new values to the admin); secondly the
    # object being referred to may not yet fully exist (#12749).
    # However, these fields *must* be included in uniqueness checks,
    # so this can't be part of _get_validation_exclusions().
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        if isinstance(field, InlineForeignKeyField):
            exclude.append(name)

    try:
        self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)

    try:
        self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)

    # Validate uniqueness if needed.
    if self._validate_unique:
        self.validate_unique()

def validate_unique(self):
    """
    Call the instance's validate_unique() method and update the form's
    validation errors if any were raised.
    """
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
    try:
        self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)

def _save_m2m(self):
    """
    Save the many-to-many fields and generic relations for this form.
    """
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    exclude = self._meta.exclude
    fields = self._meta.fields
    opts = self.instance._meta
    # Note that for historical reasons we want to include also
    # private_fields here. (GenericRelation was previously a fake
    # m2m field).
    for f in chain(opts.many_to_many, opts.private_fields):
        if not hasattr(f, 'save_form_data'):
            continue
        if fields and f.name not in fields:
            continue
        if exclude and f.name in exclude:
            continue
        if f.name in cleaned_data:
            f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Save this form's self.instance object if commit=True. Otherwise, add
    a save_m2m() method to the form which can be called after the instance
    is saved manually at a later time. Return the model instance.
    """
    if self.errors:
        raise ValueError(
            "The %s could not be %s because the data didn't validate." % (
                self.instance._meta.object_name,
                'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',
            )
        )
    if commit:
        # If committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
        self.instance.save()
        self._save_m2m()
    else:
        # If not committing, add a method to the form to allow deferred
        # saving of m2m data.
        self.save_m2m = self._save_m2m
    return self.instance

save.alters_data = True


class ModelForm(BaseModelForm, metaclass=ModelFormMetaclass):
pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `super` call. Instead of copying the variables passed to the method you overwrite them with the default values. Use this instead

```
    super().__init__( data=data, files=files, auto_id=auto_id, prefix=prefix,
                initial=initial, error_class=error_class, label_suffix=label_suffix,
                empty_permitted=empty_permitted, instance=instance, use_required_attribute=use_required_attribute,
                renderer=renderer)
```

A different option would be to simple capture all arguments:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course I overlooked that part and it makes totally sense!

Also: The last snap of code is actually really beautiful! Thanks for sharing!